# OSX 10.7.5 UTF-8 encoding over ssh

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, osx-lion

I connect to a remote linux machine over ssh and when I view a remote text file with cat command, I see incorrect incoding. It's supposed to show äöü etc, but shows garbage. I tried a luit trick,

```
luit -encoding "UTF-8" ssh remotehost
```

but on Mac it gives error

```
"Couldn't copy terminal settings"
```

Which is a known issue and apparently Apple is not going to fix it on Lion. So I am stuck now. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Mac OS that causes `tcsetattr` to fail on ptys opened with `posix_openpt`.  The workaround is to use the `openpty` function instead.

I suggest that you grab the [upstream sources](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/luit/) and recompile with `posix_openpt` disabled.